# <apex:outputField> : how to concatenate two variables

Tags: visualforce

I'm getting some errors when I try to concatenate two variables value in apex:outfield tag.
For example, if I have two variables a1 and a2, how can I get this concantenation:  value="{!a1} {!a2}"> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can't concatenate many variables or even use variables with an apex:outputField. [This visualforce tag should be used with sObject fields only!](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_actionStatus.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_actionStatus.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

As workaround you can use `apex:outputText` instead where you can do concatenation like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!a1} {!a2}" />
<apex:outputText value="{!a1 + ' ' + a2}" />
```

Or if using multiple sObject fields you will need to use multiple `apex:outputField` tags, for example in a page block table:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="My Label" />
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputField value="{!object.Field1__c}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!object.Field2__c}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it were not for the fact that it is an `<apex:outputField>`, you could use

```
{!a1 + a2}
```

You can only have one `{!...}` part in an attribute, but you can include a complete calculation within that. E.g. `{!a1+5}` or `{!a1+a2+'moreText'}` is usually perfectly valid (given the types match, of course).

Now, in an outputField `{!..}` part, you can only reference one field. So what you could do is make a formula field `'concatField'`, concatenate your values in there, and then display them using

```
{!concatField}
```

Comment: Mmm..so if I have two variables, Object1.a1 and Object1.a2 , what is the right form ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't initially see the outputField part. Updated the answer: I would suggest using a formula field if you want to keep it to one outputField.